# Test a simple function in a directive, angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This is my directive:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .directive('positionDropDowns', function (CommonFactory) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'template/position-drop-downs/position-drop-downs.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        districtsWithSubObjects: '='
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.hello = function(name){
          return 'hello ' + name;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

How do I test the `hello` function? I tried this:

```
describe('Directive: positionsDropDowns', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

  beforeEach(module('template/position-drop-downs/position-drop-downs.html'));

  var element,
    scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    element = angular.element('<position-drop-downs></position-drop-downs>');

    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));

  it('fn hello', inject(function ($compile) {
    expect(element.scope.hello('john')).toBe("hello john");

  }));
});
```

I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Try `element.scope().hello('john')` it's jquery/jqlite plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile your custom directive first:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile('<position-drop-downs></position-drop-downs>')(scope);
}));
```

After that the scope object should be populated with `hello` method:

```
it('fn hello', inject(function ($compile) {
    expect(scope.$$childTail.hello('john')).toBe("hello john");
}));
```

**URD.** zeroflagL in comments gives more elegant way to access isolated directive scope. You can also do

```
expect(element.isolateScope().hello('john')).toBe("hello john");
```

Note, that you need to access isolated directive scope. You can do it with `$$childTail` reference.

Comment: _You can do it with $$childTail reference_ - or with `element.isolateScope()`

Comment: @zeroflagL Thank you, this is useful. Didn't know about `isolateScope`.